# Proguard can't find referenced method 'void allowCoreThreadTimeOut(boolean)'

Tags: android, proguard

I'm trying to build a new release build of my Android App for the Google Play store.  I receive the following build error.

```
MyApp] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
MyApp] Warning: bolts.Executors: can't find referenced method 'void allowCoreThreadTimeOut(boolean)' in class java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
MyApp] Warning: bolts.WebViewAppLinkResolver$2$2: can't find referenced class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
MyApp]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
MyApp] Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
MyApp]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
MyApp] Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
MyApp]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
MyApp]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
MyApp]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
MyApp]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
MyApp] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
MyApp]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
MyApp]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
MyApp]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
MyApp]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

I'm not really sure how to go about fixing the issue.

I did *just* swap out the old Facebook sdk for the newest version.  Could that have something to do with this?

Answer (score 7):

The bolts library seems to refer to a method and a class that are not present in the older Android runtime that you are using for building the application. That could cause problems when you run the application on a device with this runtime. You should consider building against and targeting a more recent runtime.

If your sure that it's not a problem, you can tell ProGuard to continue anyway:

```
-dontwarn bolts.**
```